# Lua function fails when input is a multiple of ten

Tags: lua

I have a Lua Function to turn two digit integers into written words, like '12' becomes 'Twelve'. I thought I had it all working, except when I put in a number that is a direct multiple of ten (10, 20, 30 etc.) the code fails.

The specific error I get is

```
./.lua/num2word:4: attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'number' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ./.lua/num2word:4: in function 'num2wordint'
    ./.lua/num2word:117: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

But I get the right output on any other numbers.

I've tried redefining the scope of the `number` variable, but it either breaks the code on all cases, or doesn't help on the problem cases.

I've been looking at the code, and a bunch of lua support documents for a few hours now and it's beyond me.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/lua

function num2wordint(number)
    local number = number + 0
    local outstring=""
    if number / 10 >= 9 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Ninety"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Ninety-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    elseif number / 10 >= 8 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Eighty"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Eighty-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    elseif number / 10 >= 7 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Seventy"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Seventy-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    elseif number / 10 >= 6 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Sixty"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Sixty-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    elseif number / 10 >= 5 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Fifty"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Fifty-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    elseif number / 10 >= 4 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Forty"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Forty-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    elseif number / 10 >= 3 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Thirty"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Thirty-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    elseif number / 10 >= 2 then
        local remainder = number % 10
        if remainder == 0 then
            outstring= outstring.."Twenty"
        else
            outstring= outstring.."Twenty-"
            return outstring, remainder
        end
    else
        if number == 19 then
            outstring=outstring.."Nineteen"
        elseif number == 18 then
            outstring=outstring.."Eighteen"
        elseif number == 17 then
            outstring=outstring.."Seventeen"
        elseif number == 16 then
            outstring=outstring.."Sixteen"
        elseif number == 15 then
            outstring=outstring.."Fifteen"
        elseif number == 14 then
            outstring=outstring.."Fourteen"
        elseif number == 13 then
            outstring=outstring.."Thirteen"
        elseif number == 12 then
            outstring=outstring.."Twelve"
        elseif number == 11 then
            outstring=outstring.."Eleven"
        elseif number == 10 then
            outstring=outstring.."Ten"
        elseif number == 9 then
            outstring=outstring.."Nine"
        elseif number == 8 then
            outstring=outstring.."Eight"
        elseif number == 7 then
            outstring=outstring.."Seven"
        elseif number == 6 then
            outstring=outstring.."Six"
        elseif number == 5 then
            outstring= outstring .. "Five"
        elseif number == 4 then
            outstring=outstring.."Four"
        elseif number == 3 then
            outstring=outstring.."Three"
        elseif number == 2 then
            outstring=outstring.."Two"
        elseif number == 1 then
            outstring=outstring.."One"
        end
        return outstring, 0
    end
end

local words, leftOver = num2wordint(arg[1])
local i = 1
while i ~= 0 do
    local inword, inrem = num2wordint(leftOver)
    words = words .. inword
    if inrem == 0 then
        i = 0
    else
        leftOver = inrem
    end
end

print(words)
```

Comment: I wrote the same over an year ago. Please take a look at https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/8a4ec34b1c58dadf74a1#file-numbertostring-lua

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Interesting.  Your code gives wrong result for input `0` (should return string "zero") and crashes for input `100`.  BTW, `(n % 10 > 0 and num[n % 10] or '')` could be simplified to `num[n % 10]`

Comment: @hjpotter92 - One more note: `tens[0]` is defined but never used.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - It also crashes on `25`

Comment: @hjpotter92 - [Improved version of your function](http://pastebin.com/d3aFM2qv)

Comment: @Jacob If you don't pass any arguments to your script then `arg[1]` is `nil` .

Answer (score 1):

The function `num2wordint` doesn't return anything when `remainder` is `0`.

The dirty and easy fix would be to convert every snippet like:

```
    if remainder == 0 then
        outstring= outstring.."Ninety"
    else
        outstring= outstring.."Ninety-"
        return outstring, remainder
    end
```

to

```
    if remainder == 0 then
        outstring= outstring.."Ninety"
    else
        outstring= outstring.."Ninety-"
    end
    return outstring, remainder
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this would be to forget if statements and just do some table indexing. I saved some space however and just made some simple rules with some base values:

```
local num2str
do
   local bases = {[0]="","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine",[10]="ten",[11]="eleven",[12]="twelve",[13]="thirteen",[15]="fifteen",[20]="twenty",[30]="thirty",[40]="fourty",[50]="fifty",[60]="sixty",[70]="seventy",[80]="eighty",[90]="ninety"}

   function num2str(n)
      local s = tostring(n)
      if n < 20 then
         return bases[n] or bases[tonumber(s:sub(2,2))].."teen"
      else
         return bases[tonumber(s:sub(1,1))*10]..bases[tonumber(s:sub(2,2))]
      end
   end
end

for i = 1,99 do
   print(num2str(i))
end
```

Comment: Additionally if you use string keys you could eliminate the tonumber calls.